# Making two threads to continue running in background

Tags: java, android, multithreading, audio, android-asynctask

I'm writing an android app that involves one AudioTrack and one AudioRecord. They run in two different threads, and both of them need to continue to run and not being killed when low memory/CPU even if the app is running in the background. I searched about this and I know I could probably use AsyncTask (just like in music streaming app). However, I'm no exactly sure how to do it because the thread that runs AudioTrack is first created (once a certain button on the main activity is pressed), then this thread will create another thread that runs AudioRecord (by creating a Runnable).

Comment: You're probably looking at thread pooling. Check out this link: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I searched about this and I know I could probably use AsyncTask (just like in music streaming app)

No. Your issue is not the threads, but the process.

> both of them need to continue to run and not being killed when low memory/CPU even if the app is running in the background

Strictly speaking, that is not possible. The closest that you will get will be to use a `Service` that in turn uses `startForeground()` to indicate that it has foreground priority. That will minimize the probability that Android will terminate your process due to low memory conditions, but it will not eliminate it.

Also, please note that you will need the CPU to be powered on to perform your audio tasks. That, in turn, will require a `WakeLock`. This is going to seriously hammer the user's battery, to the point where you should advise users to keep the device on a charger. That will be particularly important in the future, where the "Doze mode" of the upcoming "M" Android release will block your use of `WakeLocks` if the device is idle, unmoving, and not on a charger.

Comment: Yes I understand that it's not possible for an app to not be killed in all cases. I just want to get as close to it as possible. I know that I can make it a service, but I don't think service is used for streaming music, and what my app do is just like streaming music, except that there's an extra AudioRecord that records my AudrioTrack. This streaming/recording will continue for about an hour.

Comment: @dayofdays: "I don't think service is used for streaming music" -- it is always used for streaming music. You can tell this by finding somebody with an Android device, asking them to install streaming music clients of interest to you, then noticing those apps' running services in the Apps portion of the Settings app.